# "Get a scare" or "catch a scare"

Tags: word-usage, collocation

A friend of mine insists that you can 'catch a scare', but I've only ever heard 'get a scare'. I googled the expression and mostly got 'catch a scare card' or 'catch a scare crow', with only one instance where 'cops get a scare from an incident'.

So is 'catch a scare' acceptable as correct British English or correct American English?

Comment: Never heard of 'catch a scare'. Only 'get a scare'-like expression I've heard is 'you gave me quite a scare.' What, pray tell, would those two expressions mean?

Comment: It's easily understood, obviously. But not something native speakers say. There are only two relevant instances of [caught a scare](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22caught+a+scare%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in the entire Google Books corpus.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non-existent usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: that is what I'm trying to ascertain. Note that I did find a news article using it (http://www.rutlandherald.com/article/20091103/THISJUSTIN/911030330/1003/NEWS02). If it's 'non-existent', how come a (supposedly) native journalist is using it? Could it be a regionalism?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If you'd like to post that comment as an answer, I'd accept it. Especially because I'll be citing you to my friend. :)

Comment: @Sara: Done. But note that your friend isn't really "wrong" to ***use*** the expression (*catch* is often synonymous with *get*, so it's easily understood). The error, such as it is, lies in her trying to convince you that *catch a scare* is a "normal/known" usage. It simply isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly are figurative usages involving ***catch***. For example,...

> [catch a cold](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090310074354AAnEzvL) *slang for to make a loss/lose one's investment*
>    [catch it, catch merry hell, etc.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20skanked%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22catch%20merry%20hell%22&tbm=bks) *be in serious trouble*
>    [catch on](http://www.wordreference.com/thesaurus/catch%20on) *grasp (understand)*
>    [catch the news](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20skanked%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22catch%20the%20news%22&tbm=bks) *[find time to] listen to/watch the news on radio/TV*
>   etc., etc.

But there are only two relevant instances of [caught a scare](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20skanked%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22caught%20a%20scare%22&tbm=bks) in the entire Google Books corpus (and one of those is just wordplay against *one has caught measles*). I would say it's just an exceptionally rare case of OP's friend (mistakenly?) trying to use the format in contexts where no-one else does.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not know anything about "[catch a scare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catch%20a%20scare&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)", but about "[get a scare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get%20a%20scare&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,get%20a%20scare;,c0)" it does.